use window.open() will be no responsein IE
enter image description here
when I use window.open() to create a new browser interface,in the vast majority of cases, pages crash!
Occurs only in IE
Occurs only in Windows10/11 but not in Window7
When I hit a break point at window.open(), then continue, the page loads normally
My solution for now：window.showmodaldialog(),everything is ok
I wonder what causes this problem?

I recommend against supporting IE.

Sounds like you're trying to access the window to open before it actually has been opened. Without code there's not much more we can say.
